# Converting G values into floats from an Arduino accelerometer

Tags: c, arduino, accelerometer

I am having an issue with trying to change the G values from the accelerator from int to float.  When I simply change the variable type from int to float, it's serial output looks like this while sitting still:

```
-26844 -17153 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-20133 -17217 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-26844 -17153 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-20133 -17217 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-20133 -17217 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-20133 -17217 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
-20133 -17217 -26844
mph/s: -0.17
```

While when it's just a plain int variable type, it looks normal:

```
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
0 0 1
mph/s: 0
```

However, I require the float version of the G values so that I can get an accurate calculation of the mph/s.

EDIT: The full code has been removed for confidential reasons.

```
  //we send the x y z values as a string to the serial port
  sprintf(str, "%d %d %d", xg, yg, zg);
  Serial.print(str);
  Serial.write(10);

  Serial.print("mph/s: ");
  Serial.println(mphs);

  //It appears that delay is needed in order not to clog the port
  delay(15);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code you are using for the floating point version? Note that sprintf with %d format will not work well for them.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, `xg`, `yg`, `zg` are all floats. `printf` uses different format specifiers for different data types. `"%d"` is used for integral values, `"%f"` for single-precision floating point values.

Change your code to:

```
    //we send the x y z values as a string to the serial port
    sprintf(str, "%f %f %f", xg, yg, zg);
```

You can look at the other format specifiers here: [printf Type Field Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx).

EDIT: It seems Arduino does not link floating point libraries by default. You need to enable them as described here: [Arduino: printf/fprintf prints question mark instead of float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146850/arduino-printf-fprintf-prints-question-mark-instead-of-float)

Comment: Doesn't work, it comes out like this: ? ? ?
mph/s: 0.34
? ? ?
mph/s: 0.17
? ? ?
mph/s: 0.34
? ? ?
mph/s: 0.17

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but where exactly do I put the linker flag code?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me the problem lies with sprintf statement. You are converting float Xg, Yg and Zg as %d into sprintf().

There is an old post in Stack Overflow dealing with similar problem. 
[Check that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270967/how-to-send-float-over-serial).