# qDebug - How to output data in bits (binary format)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdebug

Can qDebug() output the data in binary format?
For example, I want to check some status variation:

```
unsigned char status;
...
qDebug() << "Status: " << status;
```

I want to generate output in a binary format, something like:

```
Status: 1011
```

Comment: What do you mean "output in a binary format"? With the code you show, what would the output be?

Comment: My guess is binary representation.

Comment: @bipll: you got my point!

Comment: So if `status` is `0b10101111` you want the output to be `"Status: 10101111"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to output an int in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269767/how-to-output-an-int-in-binary)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to print in binary you can use:

1. `bin`

```
unsigned char status = 11;
qDebug() << "Status:" << bin << status;

Output:
"Status: 1011"
```

2. `QString::number()`

```
unsigned char status = 11;
qDebug() << "Status:" << QString::number(status, 2);

Output:
"Status: 1011"
```

3. `QString::arg()`

```
unsigned char status = 11;

// to print as string with 8 characters padded with '0'
qDebug() << "Status1:" << QString("%1").arg(status, 8, 2, QChar('0'));

// use noquote() if you do not want to print the quotes
qDebug().noquote() << "Status2:" << QString("%1").arg(status, 8, 2, QChar('0'));

Output:
Status1: "00001011"
Status2: 00001011
```

Comment: how to set the number of bits for ouput? My program gives 8-bit output not four bits

Comment: @jingweimo Check the last method, that's the one you want.